# logging in hapijs server with good-http plugin issue

Tags: hapi.js

I'm using [`good` plugin](https://github.com/hapijs/good) for my app, and I have copied the config parameters straight from the sample in the page, console and file are working , but [good-http](https://github.com/hapijs/good-http) is not working!

here is my configuration:

```
     myHTTPReporter: [
        {
            module: 'good-squeeze',
            name: 'Squeeze',
            args: [{error: '*', log: 'error', request: 'error'}]
        },
        {
            module: 'good-http',
            args: [
                'http://localhost/log-request/index.php?test=23424', // <- test file I created to see if data is being sent or not
                {
                    wreck: {
                        headers: {'x-api-key': 12345}
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

the only argument that is actually working is the `ops: *` and none of the `error: *, ...` is working

Am I missing something in my config parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should change the *threshold* parameter of the plugin, is set by default to 20 so it only send data after 20 events. If you want immediate results yo have to change it to 0.

```
myHTTPReporter: [
    {
        module: 'good-squeeze',
        name: 'Squeeze',
        args: [{error: '*', log: 'error', request: 'error'}]
    },
    {
        module: 'good-http',
        args: [
            'http://localhost/log-request/index.php?test=23424', // <- test file I created to see if data is being sent or not
            {
                threshold: 0,
                wreck: {
                    headers: {'x-api-key': 12345}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: threshold was the reason, and I was missing it all along. thanx